# What to do with a Spark Job that hangs on the last task?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am using https://github.com/alitouka/spark_dbscan, and to determine parameters, I am using the utility class they supply, org.alitouka.spark.dbscan.exploratoryAnalysis.DistanceToNearestNeighborDriver.

I am on a 10 node cluster with one machine with 8 cores and 32G of memory and nine machines with 6 cores and 16G of memory.

I have 442M of data, which seems like it would be a joke, but the job stalls at the last stage.

It was stuck in Scheduler Delay for 10 hours overnight, and I have tried a number of things for the last couple days, but nothing seems to be helping.

I have tried:

- Increasing heap sizes and numbers of cores
- More/less executors with different amounts of resources.
- Kyro Serialization
- FAIR Scheduling

The Spark Version is 1.4.1

The logs are full of standard fair, nothing like an exception or even interesting [INFO] lines.

Here is the script I am using: https://gist.github.com/isaacsanders/660f480810fbc07d4df2

Hadoop is: HDP 2.3.2.0-2950

Here is a gist (pastebin) of my versions en masse and a stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/isaacsanders/2e59131758469097651b

https://github.com/alitouka/spark_dbscan/blob/master/src/src/main/scala/org/alitouka/spark/dbscan/exploratoryAnalysis/DistanceToNearestNeighborDriver.scala

Comment: from the stacktrace it looks like it is computing the distances between your vectors. It's an O(n^2) loop, maybe you should try out a kd-tree or some spatial lookup structure to make it faster.

Comment: I believe there is some partitioning done based on locality in that sense. It is the distances for a much smaller subset, if I read it all correctly.

Comment: I'd guess you need to tweak the partitioning scheme a bit, maybe the distribution of your data is actually making the process running more or less sequentially.

Comment: I know this could be a little late. But this usually can happen because of imbalance of your data. I had a stage which tasks finished in 0.2 [s] average, but because of imbalance there was one hanging there in running status forever! I reshuffled the data using a distinct and algorithm finished in 2 minutes (I had too many repeated points and probably were put all together).